# How to produce づ?

Tags: discussion

I'm kind of embarrassed to have to ask this, but I honestly can't figure it out. How do you produce づ with your keyboard?

I was studying some kanji when the word 手作り came up. Since I didn't really know what it meant I tried searching for it on [Jisho](https://jisho.org/search/%E6%89%8B%E4%BD%9C%E3%82%8A) and found てづくり. A couple of seconds later I wanted to write it down in a word document and typed 'tezukuri' which resulted in the options 手頭久利 and "tezukuri", but 手作り was not there. I then noticed that I had typed in てずくり and not てづくり, so I tried 'tedzukuri' (which according to [wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiragana) seems to be the other possible way to spell this...) and again, I didn't get the option I wanted...

So what am I doing wrong here and what am I supposed to type in to get 手作り?

Note: Tested on Windows 10 machine with a japanese keyboard set up and on an iPhone 8.

Comment: This sounds like a resource question to me...

Comment: @istrasci what exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: Also related: https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/448/9831

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Microsoft Japanese IME or iPhone input, type `du` to get `づ`.